# Curl client using threads in c gives random behavior?

Tags: c, xml, curl, pthreads, libxml2

We are developing a asynchronous server for a specific project using mongoose. It takes a request, gives an immediate response, does all the parsing it needs and then responds back on a URL that is passed in the original request.

The request reception part is flawless. The response is another story though.

cant place the whole program here (propriety issues), but I have been able to make a replica such that the issue is demonstrable.

```
/*
 * xmlcrlth.c
 *
 *  Created on: Jun 28, 2012
 *      Author: mfaraz
 */

#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <libxml2/libxml/xmlreader.h>
#include <libxml2/libxml/encoding.h>
#include <libxml2/libxml/xmlwriter.h>

#define MAX_DATA_LEN            (140)
#define MAX_XML_LEN             (1024)
#define MAX_THREAD_STACK        (1024 * 1024)
//#define MY_ENCODING "ISO-8859-1"
#define MY_ENCODING "UTF-8"
#define DEFAULT_THREADS         25

//typedef
struct responseInfo {
    pthread_t   thread_id;              /*  ID returned by pthread_create() */
    int         urlLength;              /*  The Length of the URL   */
    int         xmlLength;              /*  The Length of the XML   */
    char        theXML[MAX_XML_LEN];    /*  The XML to post */
    char        theURL[MAX_DATA_LEN];   /*  The URL to post to  */
};

static void *threadCurl(void *newResponse)  {
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    struct responseInfo *thisReponse = (struct responseInfo *) newResponse;
    char thisXML[MAX_XML_LEN], thisURL[MAX_DATA_LEN];
    CURL *curlResponse;     /*  cURL variable to perform a Response */
    CURLcode curlResCode;   /*  cURL Response Code  */
    struct curl_slist *headList = NULL;
    int urlLength = strlen(thisReponse->theURL);    int xmlLength = strlen(thisReponse->theXML);
    printf("Received XML (%d vs %d bytes) using ThreadID %lu\n%s \nto URL (%d vs %d bytes) %s\n", xmlLength, thisReponse->xmlLength, thisReponse->thread_id, thisReponse->theXML, urlLength, thisReponse->urlLength, thisReponse->theURL);
//  if (urlLength != thisReponse->urlLength)
        strncpy(thisURL, thisReponse->theURL, thisReponse->urlLength);
//  if (xmlLength != thisReponse->xmlLength)
        strncpy(thisXML, thisReponse->theXML, thisReponse->xmlLength);
    /*FILE *filePtr;    char fileName[MAX_DATA_LEN] = "";   sprintf(fileName, "%lu", pthread_self());
    filePtr = fopen(fileName, "a+");
    fprintf(filePtr, "-------------------------\n");
    fprintf(filePtr, "ThreadID: %s\n", fileName);
    fprintf(filePtr, "OurlLength: %d\tCurlLength: %d\n", thisReponse->urlLength, urlLength);
    fprintf(filePtr, "OxmlLength: %d\tCxmlLength: %d\n\n", thisReponse->xmlLength, xmlLength);
    fprintf(filePtr, "OrigURL: %s\n", thisReponse->theURL);
    fprintf(filePtr, "OrigXML: %s\n", thisReponse->theXML);
    fprintf(filePtr, "NewURL: %s\n", thisURL);
    fprintf(filePtr, "NewXML: %s\n", thisXML);
    fclose(filePtr);//*/
    urlLength = strlen(thisURL);    xmlLength = strlen(thisXML);
    printf("Sending XML (%d bytes) using ThreadID %lu\n%s \nto URL (%d bytes) %s\n", xmlLength, thisReponse->thread_id, thisXML, urlLength, thisURL);
    headList = curl_slist_append(headList, "Content-Type: text/xml");
    curlResponse = curl_easy_init();
    if (curlResponse)   {
        curl_easy_setopt(curlResponse, CURLOPT_URL, thisURL);
        curl_easy_setopt(curlResponse, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headList);
//      curl_easy_setopt(curlResponse, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, xmlResp);
        curl_easy_setopt(curlResponse, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, thisReponse->xmlLength);
        curl_easy_setopt(curlResponse, CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS, thisXML);
        curl_easy_setopt(curlResponse, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_easy_setopt(curlResponse, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_easy_setopt(curlResponse, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
        curl_easy_setopt(curlResponse, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
        curl_easy_setopt(curlResponse, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
        curlResCode = curl_easy_perform(curlResponse);
        if (curlResCode)    printf("Curl Failed with status: %s!\n", curl_easy_strerror(curlResCode));
        curl_easy_cleanup(curlResponse);
    }   else    {
        printf("Curl Init Failed!\n");
        curlResCode = CURLE_FAILED_INIT;
    }
    curl_slist_free_all(headList);
    free(thisReponse);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
//  return (int)curlResCode;
}

char *getXML(int failCode, char *failDesc)  {
    int rc;
    xmlTextWriterPtr writer;
    xmlBufferPtr buf;
//    xmlChar *tmp;
    static char xmlResp[1024];  xmlResp[0] = '\0';
    /* Create a new XML buffer, to which the XML document will be written */
    buf = xmlBufferCreate();    if (buf == NULL)    printf("MTU_smac: Error creating the xml buffer\n");
    /* Create a new XmlWriter for memory, with no compression.
     * Remark: there is no compression for this kind of xmlTextWriter */
    writer = xmlNewTextWriterMemory(buf, 0);    if (writer == NULL) printf("MTU_smac: Error creating the xml writer\n");
    /* Start the document with the xml default for the version,
     * encoding ISO 8859-1 and the default for the standalone
     * declaration. */
    rc = xmlTextWriterStartDocument(writer, NULL, MY_ENCODING, NULL);   if (rc < 0) printf("MTU_smac: Error at xmlTextWriterStartDocument\n");
    /* Start an element named "svc_result". Since thist is the first
     * element, this will be the root element of the document. */
    rc = xmlTextWriterStartElement(writer, (xmlChar *)"svc_result");    if (rc < 0) printf("MTU_smac: Error at xmlTextWriterStartElement\n");
    /* Start an element named "sli_rep" as child of svc_result. */
    rc = xmlTextWriterStartElement(writer, (xmlChar *)"sli_rep");   if (rc < 0) printf("MTU_smac: Error at xmlTextWriterStartElement\n");
    /* Add an attribute with name "version" and value "1.0" to sli_rep. */
    rc = xmlTextWriterWriteAttribute(writer, (xmlChar *)"version", (xmlChar *)"3.0.0"); if (rc < 0) printf("MTU_smac: Error at xmlTextWriterWriteAttribute\n");
    /* Start an element named "pos" as child of sli_rep. */
    rc = xmlTextWriterStartElement(writer, (xmlChar *)"pos");   if (rc < 0) printf("MTU_smac: Error at xmlTextWriterStartElement\n");
    /* Write an element named "poserr" as child of pos. */
    rc = xmlTextWriterStartElement(writer, (xmlChar *)"poserr");    if (rc < 0) printf("MTU_smac: Error at xmlTextWriterStartElement\n");
    /* Write an element named "time" as child of poserr. */
    rc = xmlTextWriterWriteElement(writer, (xmlChar *)"time", (xmlChar *)"Time will Come here");    if (rc < 0) printf("MTU_smac: Error at xmlTextWriterWriteFormatElement\n");
    /* Add an attribute with name "utc" and value "+0500" to time. */
    rc = xmlTextWriterWriteAttribute(writer, (xmlChar *)"utc", (xmlChar *)"+0500"); if (rc < 0) printf("MTU_smac: Error at xmlTextWriterWriteAttribute for utc\n");
    /* Write an element named "result" as child of poserr. */
    rc = xmlTextWriterWriteFormatElement(writer, (xmlChar *)"result", "%s", failDesc);  if (rc < 0) printf("MTU_smac: Error at xmlTextWriterWriteFormatElement\n");
    /* Add an attribute with name "utc" and value "+0500" to time. */
    rc = xmlTextWriterWriteAttribute(writer, (xmlChar *)"resid", (xmlChar *)failCode);  if (rc < 0) printf("MTU_smac: Error at xmlTextWriterWriteAttribute for resid\n");
    /* Close the element named poserr. */
    rc = xmlTextWriterEndElement(writer);   if (rc < 0) printf("MTU_smac: Error at xmlTextWriterEndElement\n");
    /* Close the element named pos. */
    rc = xmlTextWriterEndElement(writer);   if (rc < 0) printf("MTU_smac: Error at xmlTextWriterEndElement\n");
    /* Start an element named "extra" as child of sli_rep. */
    rc = xmlTextWriterStartElement(writer, (xmlChar *)"extra"); if (rc < 0) printf("MTU_smac: Error at xmlTextWriterStartElement\n");
    /* Write an element named "resp_status" as child of extra. */
    rc = xmlTextWriterWriteFormatElement(writer, (xmlChar *)"resp_status", "%d", failCode); if (rc < 0) printf("MTU_smac: Error at xmlTextWriterWriteFormatElement\n");
    /* Here we could close the elements sli_rep and svc_result using the
     * function xmlTextWriterEndElement, but since we do not want to
     * write any other elements, we simply call xmlTextWriterEndDocument,
     * which will do all the work. */
    rc = xmlTextWriterEndDocument(writer);
    if (rc < 0) printf("MTU_smac: Error at xmlTextWriterEndDocument\n");
    xmlFreeTextWriter(writer);
//    printf("%s\n", (const char *) buf->content);
    sprintf(xmlResp, "%s", (const char *) buf->content);
    xmlBufferFree(buf);
    return xmlResp;
}

int postXMLResponse(char *xmlResp, char *theURL)    {
    int urlLength = strlen(theURL);
    if (urlLength == 0) return 0;   //  No URL...no Tension...!
    struct responseInfo *newResponse;
    pthread_attr_t theAttribs;
    int threadPtr;
    //  Init the threading
    threadPtr = pthread_attr_init(&theAttribs);
    if (threadPtr)  return threadPtr;
    else    printf("Thread Initialized!\n");
    //  Set the Stack size.
    threadPtr = pthread_attr_setstacksize(&theAttribs, MAX_THREAD_STACK);
    if (threadPtr)  return threadPtr;
    else    printf("Thread Stack Size set!\n");
    //  Set the Thread as Detachable.
    threadPtr = pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&theAttribs, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
    if (threadPtr)  return threadPtr;
    //  Allocate memory for the responseInfo
    newResponse = malloc(sizeof(struct responseInfo));
    if (newResponse == NULL)    return -1;
    else    printf("Structure MALLOC'ed!\n");
    int xmlLength = strlen(xmlResp);    int xmlLength2 = xmlLength;//293;
    newResponse->urlLength = urlLength;
    newResponse->xmlLength = xmlLength;
    strncpy(newResponse->theURL, theURL, urlLength);
    strncpy(newResponse->theXML, xmlResp, xmlLength2);
    printf("Threading Send XML (%d bytes)\n%s \nto URL (%d bytes) %s\n", xmlLength, newResponse->theXML, urlLength, newResponse->theURL);
    threadPtr = pthread_create(&newResponse->thread_id, &theAttribs, &threadCurl, newResponse);
    if (threadPtr)  return threadPtr;
    else    printf("Thread Created with ThreadID %lu!\n", newResponse->thread_id);
    /*FILE *filePtr;    char fileName[MAX_DATA_LEN] = "";   sprintf(fileName, "%lu", newResponse->thread_id);
    filePtr = fopen(fileName, "a");
    fprintf(filePtr, "ThreadID: %s\n", fileName);
    fprintf(filePtr, "urlLength: %d\n", newResponse->urlLength);
    fprintf(filePtr, "xmlLength: %d\n", newResponse->xmlLength);
    fprintf(filePtr, "URL: %s\n", newResponse->theURL);
    fprintf(filePtr, "XML: %s", newResponse->theXML);
    fclose(filePtr);//*/
    threadPtr = pthread_attr_destroy(&theAttribs);
    if (threadPtr)  return threadPtr;
    else    printf("Thread Attributes!\n");
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])    {
    long int iLoop, iMaxCount;
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    iMaxCount = DEFAULT_THREADS;
    if (argc > 1)   {
//      printf("Showing Arguments: -\n");   for (iLoop = 1 ; iLoop < argc ; iLoop++)    printf("%lu = %s\n", iLoop + 1, argv[iLoop]);
        iMaxCount = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    }
    for (iLoop = 0 ; iLoop < iMaxCount ; iLoop++)   {
        postXMLResponse(getXML(iLoop, "All of your base are belong to us!"), "http://localhost:80/response.php");
    }
    sleep(3);
    return 0;
}
```

You will need to set "xml2", "curl" and "pthread" for libraries and "-pthread" for the linker. Depending on your setup, you might also need to specify the actual folder for the libxml library.

When you run the program, it will try to generate 25 threads. The first argument can change that to be whatever number suits you for testing. In my tests, even a 5, results in only 3 requests landing on the webserver. Even out of those 3, one had a corrupt URL and one had a corrupt XML.

I know I am missing something for waiting for the threads to end (cant figure that out, as the main server is not going to stop).

Somebody point something wrong here!

Comment: Shouldn't you use a CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION to receive the response in?

Comment: @DanielStenberg, no it is not necessary to use the function to catch responses. We are currently not using that.

Comment: So the ~25 threads are all just writing the HTTP responses to stdout simultaneously?

Comment: Yes, we are just ignoring them.

Comment: Btw: You are aber to compile the above example code without any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might like to more properly initialise your strings.

Appling the following patch to the OP's code makes it compile and makes the output look much more proper:

```
--- main.c.orig 2012-07-07 14:11:41.000000000 +0200
+++ main.c      2012-07-07 14:09:10.000000000 +0200
@@ -4,15 +4,20 @@
  *  Created on: Jun 28, 2012
  *      Author: mfaraz
  */
+#define LIBXML_WRITER_ENABLED

+#include <unistd.h>
 #include <pthread.h>
 #include <string.h>
+#include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <time.h>
 #include <curl/curl.h>
+#include <libxml2/libxml/xmlstring.h>
 #include <libxml2/libxml/xmlreader.h>
 #include <libxml2/libxml/encoding.h>
 #include <libxml2/libxml/xmlwriter.h>
+#include <libxml2/libxml/tree.h>

 #define MAX_DATA_LEN            (140)
 #define MAX_XML_LEN             (1024)
@@ -33,7 +38,7 @@
 static void *threadCurl(void *newResponse)  {
     pthread_detach(pthread_self());
     struct responseInfo *thisReponse = (struct responseInfo *) newResponse;
-    char thisXML[MAX_XML_LEN], thisURL[MAX_DATA_LEN];
+    char thisXML[MAX_XML_LEN]="", thisURL[MAX_DATA_LEN]="";
     CURL *curlResponse;     /*  cURL variable to perform a Response */
     CURLcode curlResCode;   /*  cURL Response Code  */
     struct curl_slist *headList = NULL;
@@ -155,7 +160,7 @@
     threadPtr = pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&theAttribs, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
     if (threadPtr)  return threadPtr;
     //  Allocate memory for the responseInfo
-    newResponse = malloc(sizeof(struct responseInfo));
+    newResponse = calloc(1, sizeof(struct responseInfo));
     if (newResponse == NULL)    return -1;
     else    printf("Structure MALLOC'ed!\n");
     int xmlLength = strlen(xmlResp);    int xmlLength2 = xmlLength;//293;
```

Btw: It would be a good idea to start thinking about a different kind of source layout (as it looks like you are using Eclipse, I'd recommend the Ctrl-Shift-F magic key combination ... ;-)).

---

Also, the following line can not assure the content to be `printf()`ed hadn't had already been `free()`ed again by previously spawned thread function:

```
else    printf("Thread Created with ThreadID %lu!\n", newResponse->thread_id);
```

If `newResponse` had already been `free()`ed your app is running into undefined behavior.

Comment: OK @alk, I was able to use just 1 of your changes and get the desired result.

`char thisXML[MAX_XML_LEN]="", thisURL[MAX_DATA_LEN]="";`


Please explain why the rest is necessary - pros/cons.

Much appreciated BTW...!

Comment: Some `#include`s were necessary to make the example compile (without errors). Why the other `#include`s are necessary you see when running the compiler using its option `-Wall`. For the `calloc()` I'm sure wether is might work without it. I'll check that. @M.Faraz

Comment: You need the `calloc()` in this line `int urlLength = strlen(thisReponse->theURL);    int xmlLength = strlen(thisReponse->theXML);` at least as you **shall not** assume data returned by `malloc()` being initialised already. In case it is not initialise to zeros, the above line will try to calculate the length of some randomly fill strings (character array). @M.Faraz

Comment: You might like to run and test your application using the `valgrind` tool (http://valgrind.org/) which discovers such issues during runtime. @M.Faraz